# Umbraco forces me to update Umbraco version on localhost

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

I´m trying to start a project I pulled from a colleague. No errors, no visible issue in the project.

The project starts without problems, but immediately force me to login to Umbraco. When I enter credentials for the Admin I am returned to a view that is forcing me to upgrade Umbraco version, something I do not want to do since the project is live on the Umbraco I´m currently on.

I have worked with Umbraco before on several project and never experienced this issue.

The project is running fine on my colleagues computer, connected to the same umbraco database. He has no changes that are not committed to the repository I´m pulling the project from.

Any ideas what might be causing this situation?

Umbraco v6.2.6 (Assembly version: 1.0.5906.18846)

Thanks and best regards, Martin

Comment: This is probably caused by a difference in version in the database (umbracoMigration table) and the version defined in the web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the version of Umbraco in the core DLLs matches the one that's in the "umbracoConfigurationStatus" appSettings key in your web.config file. If they're different, it'll try and get you to upgrade. Compare against your colleagues machine as well to see if there's a difference between what's on his machine and yours.

You get the upgrade message when Umbraco detects a mismatch between the version it's running and what the web.config file says the site is running.

Comment: This worked! Thanks alot. Strange thing is that all of out config files are identical, only difference is the umbraco.core.dll and umbraco.dll product version.

So our umbracoConfigurationStatus is identical, and same with packages config. But still different DLL versions...